# Is it possible to have a spinner filled from specific field of an ArrayList of a class?

Tags: android, data-binding, arraylist, spinner

I have an arrayList of this class:

```
public class Lawyer extends DbHelper{
    private int id;
    private String fullName;
    private String mobile;

    private Context context;

    public Lawyer(Context context,int id, String fullName, String mobile) {
        super(context);
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.mobile = mobile;

        this.context = context;     
    }
}
```

My arrayList is filled with information of a few people. Is it possible to have a spinner filled with "fullName" of all lawyers in the array list?
Currently I have this code to fill my spinner with static data from a simple array:

```
String [] items={"Lawyer1","Lawyer2","Lawyer3","Lawyer4","Lawyer5"};
final Spinner lstLawyers;

lstLawyers=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.lstLawyers);
lstLawyers.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items));
lstLawyers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        EditText txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        txtMessage.setText(lstLawyers.getSelectedItem().toString());

    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at SpinnerAdaper.

If you have an alTypes ArrayList with  Lawyer classes (with  fullName, mobile etc...)
you should extend SpinnerAdapter (see AdapterForSpinner1 below)

and then set it to your spinner like this:

```
AdapterForSpinner1 spinad1 = new AdapterForSpinner1(activity, alTypes);

             lstLawyers.setAdapter(spinad1);
```

**AdapterForSpinner1**

```
class AdapterForSpinner1 extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

    /**
     * The internal data (the ArrayList with the Objects).
     */
    private final List<Lawyer> data;
    Context mContext;

    public AdapterForSpinner1(Context context, List<Lawyer> data){
        this.data = data;
        mContext=context;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Size of the ArrayList
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns one Element of the ArrayList
     * at the specified position.
     */
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the View that is shown when a element was
     * selected.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View recycle, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text;
        if (recycle != null){
            // Re-use the recycled view here!
            text = (TextView) recycle;
        } else {
            // No recycled view, inflate the "original" from the platform:
             LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            text = (TextView) (li.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false)          );
        }
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        text.setText(data.get(position).getFullname());
        return text;
    }


}
```